# SDL2_mixer framework OSX gcc compiler error

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, frameworks, sdl-2

When I compile the frameworks for SDL2 I'm having no problems, except when I compile the SDL2_mixer.framework.

Here is the code for the compiler, I use rpath to a custom location/directory because I want to be able to move it between computers with no compiler errors, and it works, although like I mentioned before it is having problems with the mixer (Audio) framework in SDL2.

```
echo "OSX/Darwin"
FLAGS=""
FLAGS+="-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT "
FLAGS+="-F $(pwd)/SDL_runner/SDL_frameworks/OSX/ "
FLAGS+="-framework SDL2 "
FLAGS+="-framework SDL2_mixer "
FLAGS+="-framework SDL2_image "
FLAGS+="-framework SDL2_ttf "
FLAGS+=-"rpath $(pwd)/SDL_runner/SDL_frameworks/OSX/ "
```

The GCC compiler code, The $compilecpp $compilec and $compileo are just all the cpp, o, and hpp files in the directory and subdirectories. Those three variables are also not causing the problem.

```
g++ -Wall $compilecpp $compilec $compileo -o run -DMAC $FLAGS
```

The includes.

```
#ifdef MAC
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_mixer/SDL_mixer.h>
#endif
```

And lastly the error I'm getting from it, is only pertaining to SDL2_mixer.framwork saying that the image doesn't exist, even though I implemented it in the exact same fashion as the rest of the frameworks.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL2.framework/
Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Users/jordan/Documents/GaleFoxGames/graphic_render/
OpenGL_dis4/SDL_runner/SDL_frameworks/OSX/SDL2_mixer.framework/Versions/
A/Frameworks/smpeg2.framework/Versions/A/smpeg2
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL2 Mixer framework is broken on OSX.

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: SDL2 mixed (not sure about now) is a broken package and fails to compile when included.

Comment: this is of course in the current context of the question.

Comment: ok thanks. I thought it was 'global knowledge' that the package is broken. Which seemed relevant since I was having some issues bundling the thing ;^)   Thanks for clearing it up

Comment: I may be possible that your issue is related to that, I wasn't able to get that package working with G++ std=gnu11 or 14 I believe. The rest of SDL worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it supposed to be

```
FLAGS+=-"rpath $(pwd)/SDL_runner/SDL_frameworks/OSX/ "
```

or

```
FLAGS+="-rpath $(pwd)/SDL_runner/SDL_frameworks/OSX/ "
```

Comment: It's rpath, when i enter -rpath it spits out another error saying --rpath is not a supported option